# sorting columns independently at array level

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with several columns that I need to sort individually.
I wrote the script below that works but is a bit slow since it handles each column in turn with `getValues()` and `setValues()`.
I'd like to find a way to do the whole sorting at an array level for more efficiency but I don't know how... any suggestion ?

Here is the relevant part of the code I use now :

```
...
  sh3.getRange(1,1,1,newData[0].length).setFontWeight('bold');// newData is an array corresponding to the whole sheet
  for(col=1;col<newData[0].length;++col){
    var val = sh3.getRange(2,col,getLastRowInCol(col),1).getValues().sort();// each column have a different height
    sh3.getRange(2,col,getLastRowInCol(col),1).setValues(val)
    }
}

function getLastRowInCol(col){
  var values = sh3.getRange(2,col,sh3.getLastRow(),1).getValues();// skip header and find last non empty row in column
  for(n=0;n<values.length;++n){
    if(values[n]==''){break}
  }
  return n
}
```

**Note :** *I know there is a [Library by Romain Vialard](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library) that does the job (sorting columns in 2D arrays) but I'm interrested on how to do it 'manually' for personal JS skills improvement ;-) and also I need to sort every column independently without needing to update the sheet for every column.*

Comment: Re: function getLastRowInCol(col) -- will return the first cell that precedes a blank cell. If there is a blank in the list it will not continue beyond. Better to start at the bottom and work your way up looking for the first cell with data.

Comment: *will return the first cell that precedes a blank cell.* I know but since I start on row 2 that happend to be good ;-) and your right about startin from the end but I have a lot more 'short columns than 'long one' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
function sortColumns() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var startCol = 1;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, sheet.getLastRow() - startRow + 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - startCol + 1);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  // transpose data so each column item will be listed in an single array
  // for each column so that it can be sorted with array.sort()
  var rowToCol = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    rowToCol.push([]);
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      // replace empty string with undefined as undefined sorts last
      rowToCol[i].push(data[j][i]==""?undefined:data[j][i]);
    }
    rowToCol[i].sort();
    // default sort, as above, is alphabetic ascending. For other methods
    // search for Javascript array sort functions
  }

  // transpose sorted items back to their original shape
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rowToCol[0].length; i++) {
    result.push([]);
    for (var j = 0; j < rowToCol.length; j++) {
      result[i].push(rowToCol[j][i]==undefined?"":rowToCol[j][i]);
    }
  }
  dataRange.setValues(result);
};


function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Sort Columns",
    functionName : "sortColumns"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};
```

Comment: You may want this to handle 0 values too.

Comment: +BryanP You are correct. This can only be used for simple alpha sort with out modifying the sort with a function. To sort numerically or case insensitive there are array sort functions online that can be found to augment the above.

Comment: Thx Michael, while trying I didn't think about adding the sort where you put it... your code is cristal clear ;-) thanks

Comment: Performance increase : about 20 to 1 ... not bad @ScampMichael ^^

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @Serge. That's great to hear. I may even add a few comments to the code.

Comment: just one detail, what is `result.push([]);` for ? (7 th line before end) can you briefly explain ? thx

Comment: result is an array and result.push([]) creates and empty array within the result array to receive the columns of the row. The next iteration through the loop the result.push([]) creates another empty array within result to receive the next row of column items. -- result.push([]) creates an empty array for each row which gets filled by the next loop.

Comment: ok, if I understand you well it does the same as initiating an array for every row and push this new array in the first one right after the 'j' for loop... hum, that's not clear I know but I understand myself and I see what you mean, it is much more simple and straightforward to use your way... thanks for the lesson ;-) , another thing that I ignored and that I now know... I can tell you : in ten years I'll be a great JS programmer (if my brain doesn't blow up before ;-D)

Comment: We have both learned a lot since entering the program. If you keep it up at this pace for another ten years, Watch out Larry Page.

Comment: @ScampMichael - I reused that function and came to an issue : undefined didn't come last but first ... an idea ? I replaced by 'zzzzz' and it worked but I don't like too much that solution. thx in advance ;-)

Comment: Hey Serge, I ran the script and it worked as I expected with all blank cells at the bottom of the column. Are you sure your blank cells are empty? No spaces and the should not contain anything including the word undefined. Try deleting the blanks just to make sure. You also might try len(cell) to make sure it returns 0.